# SVG - How to show/hide multiple elements on a button click

Tags: javascript, svg

This is my SVG code; I have given the elements a class name:

```
<path class="Myrect" clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#61AFB5" d="M101.5,206c0,0-5.1-13.4-6.5-24.6c0,0-22.9,3.1-23,3.1c-0.1,0,1,16.6,7.8,31.4L101.5,206z"/>
<path class="Myrect" clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#61AFB5" d="M155.8,62.3c0,0,12.2-7,22.9-10c0,0-6.4-22.5-6.4-22.6c0-0.1-15.9,3.3-29.2,12.3L155.8,62.3z"/>
<path class="Myrect" clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#61AFB5" d="M119,90.8c0,0,8.5-10.5,17.1-17c0,0-13.4-17.5-13.4-17.6c0-0.1-13.1,8.6-22,21.2L119,90.8z"/>
```

This is my button code

```
<button onclick="hideSVG();">hide/show</button>
```

This is my JS code

```
function hideSVG() {
    var style = document.getElementsByClassName('Myrect').style.display;
if(style === "none")
    document.getElementsByClassName('Myrect').style.display = "block";
else
    document.getElementsByClassName('Myrect').style.display = "none";
}
```

and it is not working. Any idea how can I make this work?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('Myrect') is an array of elements. So you may need to specify which array element: document.getElementsByClassName('Myrect')[0] or iterate through them in a for loop

Comment: How can I iterate through them and where do I put that code of iteration?

Comment: Don't update all the elements in the class, update the class definition itself so that the class Myrect is either display: block or none.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, and you can't set `style` on that. (You also can't *get* style as a property that way.)

You need to iterate over the nodes in that list. There are a few different ways you could do this; here's one.

```
// look up the nodes, store the reference
var rects = document.getElementsByClassName('Myrect');

// this is just a counter for looping
var i;

// loop over those nodes
for (i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
  rects[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

As far as how to get the style in the first place - that depends on whether these elements are all supposed to change style together, or whether each one is being checked and changed individually. If they're all the same, you could just look up `rects[0].style.display`. If they're not, you can move the `if()` condition into the loop, like

```
var rects = document.getElementsByClassName('Myrect');
var i;

for (i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
  if (rects[i].style.display == "none") {
    rects[i].style.display = "block";
    return;
  }
  rects[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

I'm attaching a runnable snippet so you can see what I mean:

```js
function toggleDisplay() {
  var rects = document.getElementsByClassName('Myrect');
  var i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    if (rects[i].style.display == 'none') {
      rects[i].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      rects[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 80 20">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10" fill="skyblue" class="Myrect" />
  <rect x="30" y="10" width="10" height="10" fill="orange" class="Myrect" />
  <rect x="50" y="10" width="10" height="10" fill="skyblue" class="Myrect" />
</svg>

<button onclick="toggleDisplay()">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: You mean instead of each document.getElementsByClassName('Myrect').style.display is should put rects[0].style.display ? because I have added the first code and it didn't work.

Comment: The first code block in my answer is just enough to change all of those nodes to `display: block`. For the logic to switch between block and display, reread the rest of the answer. Can you be more specific about "it didn't work"? Are you seeing any errors in your browser console?

Comment: I am testing what I am doing in an HTML page, I added the code you gave me and when I test the button of show/hide nothing happen to those objects

Comment: My object code is something like this  <path class="Myrect" clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#61AFB5" d="M101.5,206c0,0-5.1-13.4-6.5-24.6c0,0-22.9,3.1-23,3.1c-0.1,0,1,16.6,7.8,31.4
   L101.5,206z"/>

Comment: How can I add the class name in this code, it starts with path not rect..

Comment: The class name is already in that code. `class="Myrect"`. So you'd need to modify the snippet I gave slightly - `var rects = document.getElementsByClassName('MyRect');`

Answer (score 0):

Updated your function:

```
function hideSVG() {
var obj = document.getElementsByClassName('Myrect');
    for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
        if(obj[i].style.display === "none"){
            obj[i].style.display = "block";
        }else{
            obj[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my function. it works but only with one of the objects. Not the three of them, I have given class="Myrect" to three objects..

Comment: THANK YOU IT WORKED